# How do redundant memory cells in DRAM raise yield?

Tags: memory, computer-architecture, dram

I was recently reading Computer Architecture-A Quantitative Approach(6th edition), and I encountered a problem while trying to understand a section from page 34:

```
Given the tremendous price pressures on commodity products such as DRAM and SRAM, designers 
have included redundancy as a way to raise yield. For a number of years, DRAMs have regularly
included some redundant memory cells so that a certain number of flaws can be accommodated.
```

Doesn't yield actually refer to the number of DRAMs (out of many DRAMs manufactured in bulk) that make through the testing-procedure? If it is the case, how does adding redundant memory cells to a single DRAM increases that DRAM's yield chance. Furthermore, what are some examples of "certain number of flaws" that the line refers to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say you are making a DRAM chip that requires 64 cells to provide 32GB of RAM (I just made this up; no real numbers/data were harmed in the creation of this response).

If you build 64-cell chips have a defect rate of 0.1 cell defects per chip ( or 0.1/64 = 0.0016 defects per cell), that means that roughly one out of every 10 chips (or 10 out of every hundred) will have to be thrown away as unusable.

If instead you build 65-cell chips, and a small amount of additional circuitry that simply disables one cell chosen after first round testing, then you can tolerate one cell defect and still produce a usable 32GB part that passes testing.

Put another way, out of a batch of 100 chips, instead of throwing away 10 due to one defect, you can do a first round of testing to see if one cell can be identified as failing, activate the circuitry to disable that cell, and then run the chip through final testing to confirm function / quality.  This should let you keep about 9 more chips out of that batch of 100 (the last chip will have 2 defects sometimes) raising your yield from 90% to about 99.5%, despite the fact that you added another cell that could also fail.

The statistics is mildly interesting if you are into that type of thing; I'd be happy to give it a shot if you're curious.

A flaw is generally a failure in the chip production process that results in a portion of the chip not functioning as designed.  That could conceivably be due to impurities in materials, failures in masking, failures in placing the chip material in the chip package... anything.  Not all types of flaws can be mitigated by this approach.